# Do equivalent metrics preserve completeness on metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on the set X are said to be equivalent if and only if every open set in $(X, d)$ is also open in $(X, d')$ and vice versa. Or the identity map from $(X, d)$ to $(X, d')$ is continuous.

Is it necessary that if $(X, d)$ is complete, then $(X, d')$ is also complete?
Also, is it necessary that if $(X, d)$ is sequentially compact, then $(X, d')$ is also sequentially compact?

Thank you.

Comment: Another, stronger, sense of "equivalent" is that the identity maps from $(X,d)$ to $(X,d')$ and vice versa are both *uniformly* continuous.  In that case completeness is preserved.  Yet another sense is that both maps are Lipschitz, which is even stronger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness, no: consider the equivalent metrics $d_1(x,y)=\lvert \arctan x-\arctan y\rvert$ and $d_2(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$ on $\Bbb R$.

For metric spaces sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness, which is a topological property: therefore, yes in that regard.

**Added:** It should be pointed out that (topological) equivalence of $d$ and $d'$ is not equivalent to $id:(X,d)\to (X,d')$ being continuous, but to $id:(X,d)\to (X,d')$ being a homeomorphism.